# unix utility to merge files without space overhead (cat *.txt > merged.txt;rm *.txt in one step)

Tags: utilities

Is there a utility that dumps a file line by line to stdout and deletes those lines?

I have a number of large files that I want to merge via `cat`. Of course I could do

```
cat *.txt > merged.txt
```

But this will take double the space originally occupied by the `txt` files. Deleting them after `cat` like so

```
cat *.txt > merged.txt && rm -rf *.txt
```

reduces the storage requirements but still needs 2x the space to be present in the meantime

I'm looking for a command that would stream lines to stdout while at the same time deleting them in the original files:

```
<some command> *.txt > merged.txt
```

such that the total space used by `*.txt` + `merged.txt` and is never more that what `*.txt` needed originally

Answer (score 0):

Line by line sounds a bit tricky, but if you accept to do it file by file (so that storage never exceeds all `*.txt` files + one of them:

```
find -name "*.txt" -exec cat {} >> result.txt \; -exec \rm -f {} \;
```

**BE VERY CAREFUL**! Always check the result of your find command before running it, or you'll be `rm`'ing stuff that should not be deleted at lightspeed.